# Looking for redacted text corpus

Tags: dataset, natural-language

I am looking around for datasets mainly in the form of natural language text corpus, that has been redacted by experts. So far I found only the [enron](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/) dataset, but it appears only a few specific things (like employee mail-id, etc.) were redacted, which will not be beneficial for feature extraction.

Something like declassified government records or company data would be awesome; medical records would probably be comparatively easier to get, but are quite unrelated to the problem. Any idea if such dataset is available?

Comment: What about open access scientific publications? One of the large collections is http://www.biomedcentral.com/ .

Comment: I'm curious what kind your goal is, how do you want to use the data?

Comment: @John Salvatier the goal is redacted :D ... actually I want to do some analysis on what kind of information generally gets redacted in free form text documents. In other words what sorts of information do people consider sensitive - and if its possible to use some machine learning algorithms to aid automatic redaction. I read sometime back Xerox had something like this - but there's no more info on how that can be done. I have some idea I want to try out, but no data ...

Comment: Won't you need both the redacted and un-redacted datasets to make your determination? Otherwise, are you simply speculating, "Hmmm... looks like they redacted names here", or "Hmmm... I'd guess those are phone numbers."?

Comment: That is an excellent point. We could not find a solution to that - and nobody was willing to give such data. For the sake of reproducibility, I had to redesign the problem from an entirely different perspective that would make some sense to reviewers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a big database of documents that came out in the tobacco lawsuits at the [Legacy Tobacco Documents Library](http://legacy.library.ucsf.edu/).  Try using the expert search interface, and search on "partially redacted".

Answer (score 1):

For medical data, a few datasets can be found at: [Physician notes with annotated PHI](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6676/1652)

1) [i2b2 2006 Deidentification and Smoking Challenge's data set](https://i2b2.org/NLP/DataSets/):

> NLP Data Set #1B:  889 de-identified discharge summaries with
>   de-identification challenge annotations, training and test sets and
>   ground truth.
>
> Please cite as:
>
> Uzuner Ö., Juo Y, Szolovits P. "Evaluating the state-of-the-art in
>   automatic de-identification".  J Am Med Inform Assoc. 2007,
>   14(5):550-63. http://www.jamia.org/cgi/content/abstract/14/5/550 .

2) [i2b2 NLP Data Set #7a: De-identification Challenge Data Set](https://i2b2.org/NLP/DataSets/):

> Please cite as:
>
> - Stubbs A, Uzuner Ö. (2015). "Annotating longitudinal clinical narratives for de-identification: The 2014 i2b2/UTHealth corpus". J
>     Biomed Inform. 2015 Aug 28. pii: S1532-0464(15)00182-3. doi:
>     10.1016/j.jbi.2015.07.020. [Epub ahead of print]. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26319540.
> - Stubbs A, Kotfila C, Uzuner Ö. (2015). "Automated systems for the de-identification of longitudinal clinical narratives: Overview of
>     2014 i2b2/UTHealth shared task Track 1". J Biomed Inform. 2015 Jul 28.
>     pii: S1532-0464(15)00117-3. doi: 10.1016/j.jbi.2015.06.007. [Epub
>     ahead of print]. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26225918.

3) [i2b2 2016](https://www.i2b2.org/NLP/RDoCforPsychiatry/)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170428025812/https://www.i2b2.org/NLP/RDoCforPsychiatry/)) CEGS N-GRID challenge; Track 1: De-identification.

4) https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/deid/

> The deid software package was developed and tested using a gold standard corpus of 2,434 nursing notes that have been thoroughly deidentified by a multi-pass process that included meticulous reviews by three or more experts working independently, as well as by a variety of automated methods. All detected instances of PHI in these nursing notes have been replaced by realistic surrogate data in the gold standard corpus. Although the deid software, as noted above, may be redistributed under the terms of the GPL, the gold standard corpus, because of the very small possibility that it may contain one or more instances of undetected PHI, is currently available only under terms that do not permit it to be redistributed.

- Goldberger AL, Amaral LAN, Glass L, Hausdorff JM, Ivanov PCh, Mark RG, Mietus JE, Moody GB, Peng C-K, Stanley HE. PhysioBank, PhysioToolkit, and Physionet: Components of a New Research Resource for Complex Physiologic Signals. Circulation 101(23):e215-e220 [Circulation Electronic Pages; http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/101/23/e215.full]; 2000 (June 13).
- Neamatullah I, Douglass M, Lehman LH, Reisner A, Villarroel M, Long WJ, Szolovits P, Moody GB, Mark RG, Clifford GD. Automated De-Identification of Free-Text Medical Records. BMC Medical Informatics and Decision Making, 2008, 8:32. doi:10.1186/1472-6947-8-32

---

In case anyone is interested, we presented an overview of the state-of-the art results on these two datasets in:

- Franck Dernoncourt, Ji Young Lee, Ozlem Uzuner, Peter Szolovits. [De-identification of Patient Notes with Recurrent Neural Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475). Journal of the American Medical Informatics Association (JAMIA). 2016.
- Ji Young Lee, Franck Dernoncourt, Ozlem Uzuner, Peter Szolovits. [De-Feature-Augmented Neural Networks for Patient Note De-identification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09704).  International Conference on Computational Linguistics (COLING) Clinical NLP. 2016.